# jQuery .detach / append in if/else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, detach

I'm having a bit a trouble with creating a category filter for my custom post type taxonomy, I've tried allot of different things in jQuery and I think this should be the best way to get what I want.

Code:

```
var divs;

$('.category').on('click', function() {
    if(divs == 1) {
        alert('ayylmao?');
        $('section#showcase').append(detached);
        divs = 0;
    } else {
        divs = 1;
        var lolxd = $(this).find('a').attr('id');
        alert(lolxd);
        var detached = $('section#showcase').contents().not("." + lolxd).detach(); 
    }
});
```

It has been a while ago that I used jQuery but for some reason the var 'detached' wont append to the section showcase.

Would like to hear what I am doing wrong ;_;

Comment: I think since your variable `detached` is only local to the function, once your `divs` value is 1, `detached` is undefined, try doing a `console.log` of it inside your `if`

Comment: `var divs, detached;`, `detached = $('section#showcase').contents().not("." + lolxd).detach()`

Comment: oke yep, it says undefined. Any idea on what I should change?

Comment: One option is to declare `detached` as a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

`detached` is declared *within* your click handler function. That means it's re-created every time the function runs.

Contrast that to your use of `divs` which is declared outside the function and thus persists across function calls.

There are many ways to solve this, but the simplest would be to follow the same pattern that you have for `divs` and have code that looks like this:

```
var divs;
var detached;
$('.category').on('click', function() {
    if(divs == 1) {
        alert('ayylmao?');
        $('section#showcase').append(detached);
        divs = 0;
    } else {
        divs = 1;
        var lolxd = $(this).find('a').attr('id');
        alert(lolxd);
        detached = $('section#showcase').contents().not("." + lolxd).detach(); 
    }
});
```

Speaking more generally, it sounds like when you detach a showcase, you want to keep it around so you can add it back later. Depending on the makeup of your program, it might be more useful to just change the `display` of that item to `none`. However, this does change the semantics if you had multiple things you could append to your showcase.

Comment: Ye the problem with that is that I am using nth-child for every 3rd, 4rth and fifth item. Also thanks for helping it is almost working correctly now (: